# Tensorflow results inconsistent between each freeze graph

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

When freezing a graph and then running it elsewhere (mobile device), the output is of low quality compared to the inference on the server on my semantic segmentation model. It is basically a messy version of what would run on the server. It is executing successfully, but it appears as though something was not initialized prior to freezing, even though the method to load the model between the export script and inference scripts is nearly identical.

The exported model can be run on the same images over and over and produce the same results for a given set of images, as expected.

However, each time the model is frozen, using the exact same script and checkpoint, it creates a different output for a given set of images.

```
def main():
    args = get_arguments()

    if args.dataset == 'cityscapes':
        num_classes = cityscapes_class
    else:
        num_classes = ADE20k_class

    shape = [320, 320]

    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(shape[0], shape[1], 3), name="input")
    img_tf = preprocess(x)

    model = model_config[args.model]
    net = model({'data': img_tf}, num_classes=num_classes, filter_scale=args.filter_scale)

    raw_output = net.layers['conv6_cls']
    raw_output_up = tf.image.resize_bilinear(raw_output, size=shape, align_corners=True)
    raw_output_maxed = tf.argmax(raw_output_up, axis=3, name="output")

    # Init tf Session
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    sess.run(init)

    model_path = model_paths[args.model]
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        input_checkpoint = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path
        loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
        load(loader, sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)     
    else:
        print('No checkpoint file found at %s.' % model_path)
        exit()

    print("Loaded Model")

    # We retrieve the protobuf graph definition
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
        input_graph_def, # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes
        output_node_names.split(",") # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
    )

    # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
    with tf.gfile.GFile("model/output_graph.pb", "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
    print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))
```